# Colocar form no centro

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Alguém saberia como centralizar um *form* dentro de um *container* com *bootstrap?

Exemplo:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Centralizar este form -->
            <form>
            ....
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quer centralizar o bloco todo  do `form` ou  o conteúdo dele(`labels`, `inputs` ...)?

Comment: o bloco inteiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer o que quer é utilizando o [Offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting), assim você consegue controlar o tamanho dos campos e a margem à esquerda do form, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
            <!-- Centralizar este form -->
            <form>
              <h1>FORM</h1>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                  <label>Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                  <label>Idade</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***OBS: Note que para cada tamanho de tela (xs,sm,md,lg), terá que configurar de uma maneira, portanto teste todos os tamanhos.***

Comment: Na verdade não é centralizado, o que a classe `col-*-offset-*` é dar um `margem` na esquerda em relação ao elemento pai, que nem você citou na resposta! Serve para mover elementos para direita.

Comment: @IgorMello correto, ele não centraliza, aumenta a margem esquerda movendo os elementos para a direita que de certa forma "centraliza" o form na tela, o que eu acredito ser o principal objetivo dele.

Comment: Ok, atendendo a necessidade dele, é o caso!

Answer (score -1):

Se utilizar uma versão de HTML anterior à 5, pode utilizar:

```
<center></center>
```

Se utilizar HTML5, tem de utilizar CSS:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```